# Why does PHPUnit not detect a *Test.php file?

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm working on https://github.com/klausi/drupalpractice and have ProjectUnitTest.php in Test/ProjectDetection.

When I execute

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

it passes and tells me OK (19 tests, 10 assertions).

When I execute

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit Test/ProjectDetection/
```

It suddenly fails with a PHP Fatal error:  Class 'DrupalPractice_Project' not found in Test/ProjectDetection/ProjectUnitTest.php on line 37

Why doesn't the first phpunit execution without arguments fail as well? Why does PHPUnit not pick up the test file in Test/ProjectDetection/?

Comment: Why is the OP not posting the fatal error? Why is the OP not realizing other people need to see what goes on, which is augmented by posting all the relevant information?

Comment: Fixed, added the PHP fatal error message :-)

Comment: There we go :) it's clear what goes on now. Did you specify an autoloader that would load Drupal's classes maybe? Looks like you missed it, it's configurable via phpunit.xml if I recall correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I have not figured out a autoloading strategy yet since this is based on PHPCS which does not use namespaces and PSR-0 :-(

Comment: You can specify a bootstrap file for phpunit, and that one can include or specify all the autoloaders you need (composer autoloader or drupal autoloader, entirely up to you).